# Unable to call methods from other classes in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

1. When using Windows cmd (and Notepad++) i am able to call methods from other classes if they are all in default package
2. However, I am unable to do so if i define classes in any package other than default package.
3. Am facing this problem in NetBeans and Eclipse as well

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you please add your code attempts so other SO users can better understand what the issue is and how you are actually calling these other methods.

Comment: “I am unable to do so” Why?  What happened, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining class in package-A,
it must be **public**, if you want to use it in package-B

```
package package-A;
public class A{
    public void hello();
}

package package-B;
public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        a.hello();
    }

}
```

Because by-default access-modifier is **default**, so it will be accessable in that particular package only.

To learn more about access modifiers : [Click Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/)